# How to check how much ms is bool variable true in one second?

Tags: c++, time, percentage, clock, stopwatch

i want to measure how much % of 1 second is for example bool m_Wheel true.

Please help i dont know how to do it

```
    static int upTrueCount = 0;
    static int downTrueCount = 0;

    time_t start = time(0);

    if (start < 1)
    {
        if (cvar.m_Wheel_up)
            upTrueCount += 1;

        if (cvar.m_Wheel_down)
            downTrueCount += 1;
    }


    if (cvar.m_Wheel_up)
        value += 3 + upTrueCount;

    if (cvar.m_Wheel_down)
        value -= 3 + downTrueCount;

    cvar.m_Wheel_up = false;
    cvar.m_Wheel_down = false;

    upTrueCount = 0;
    downTrueCount = 0;
```

Simply, I just want to add more value than +=3 when scrolling mouse wheel faster

Comment: You could check m_Wheel a hundred times in one second, the number of times is true should be roughly the percentage of time it is true?

Comment: You can write some wrapper around `m_Wheel` and measure time between its setting/resetting. Just note that time measurements themselves take some overhead, therefore, your obtained number will not be fully accurate.

Comment: Can you make example code please

Comment: I agree with Daniel - don't sample or poll, but instead record timestamps and do some maths to figure out the percentage of "on"-ness during each one-second time slice. This would be a good general solution. Then again, for your stated goal of detecting faster scrolls, you probably want something a bit simpler, like incrementing some flag and having a timer keep decrementing it in a thread. This will also result in an "instant" change in velocity, which you won't have if you wait a second before doing anything. You'll have to do some logical thinking about what this algorithm might look like.